# Rendering whole numbers as floats in PHP JSON response

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, lumen

I am passing JSON response as below in PHP webservice (Lumen)

```
$obj = ['test' => 0.0 ];
return $res = json_encode($obj);
```

But its response is casted to integer. See below

```
{"test":0}
```

I am expecting it as floating point number 0.0 (not a string) in the response.

Comment: Make it a string before json, PHP don't like floats with zero as decimal.

Comment: Tried it already but response is {"test":"0.0"}. I want it as {"test":0.0}

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Comment: {"test":0.0} is a valid json. So the device that is consuming the service is expecting response in this format.

Comment: Yes valid in json, but not in PHP. https://3v4l.org/QhNIU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values such 0.0, 1.0 and so on are whole numbers there's nothing wrong in this case.

But if you insist to keep the type of the variable you may do it like this:

```
json_encode($obj, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
```